# Create HTML grid from output of rectangle packing algorithm

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I'm using the [rectpack](https://github.com/secnot/rectpack) python library to obtain the optimal rectangle packing positions for `div` elements that contain d3 charts. I have the `height, width, bottom-left corner x coordinate, bottom-left corner y coordinate` for the `div` elements on a 1200px wide canvas that looks like the plot below. [image]

**Note**: Due to the nature of the project I have to `iframe` the d3 chart HTML in my grid. I only have the width and height info for the charts and they may also be later replaced by another kind of charts like bokeh chart HTML outputs for example. So, positioning the divs is my only options for this.

I need to translate this into a HTML grid but since I'm not a web developer I'm kind of stuck as to how to create such a grid with the information above. I'm using the `jinja2` templating engine to create this. However, I'm stuck trying to position the divs exactly since there doesn't seem to be an obvious place to add the position information outside css. But since each element is unique, dynamically creating css for each element doesn't seem to be optimal.

What would be the best approach in this scenario?

Comment: D3 objects (rectangles) have attributes like "x" and "y" that you could set using JSON data. It would take a bit of wrangling of rectpack's representation of (x,y) coordinates, transforming to a set of (x,y) coordinates that D3 would understand, but packing it up as a Python dictionary, then using `json.dumps(d)`, is a good way to get data out of Python and into D3.

Comment: yes, that would be my approach but the problem here is that I'm Iframing the d3 charts inside the divs and don't have access to the code that's creating them. D3 might be replaced by something else as well, I just have the plot height and width information. So, I'm stuck having to work with the divs only. I should have mentioned that as well. Doing that now.

Comment: Here's a post that might help with the second step: [d3.js - adding rectangles reading from JSON file in an svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375494/d3-js-adding-rectangles-reading-from-json-file-in-a-svg). Can you post what a simple rectpack set of rectangles looks like?